# Processing Square Stacking loop

Tags: processing

This is my first time writing here so i'll be direct, i've been trying to recreate this image:

[image: Loop]

and so far all the code i've got is:

```
void setup() {
size(500, 500);
}

void draw() {
rectMode(CENTER);
recta();
}


void recta() {
noFill();
int a = 10;
int y = 250;

for (int x = 0; x<20; x++) {

pushMatrix();
translate(y, y);
rect(0, 0, a, a);
popMatrix();
rotate(radians(2.0*PI));

stroke(0, 0, 0);
a= a - 20;
 }
}
```

And i have no idea what to do next since this is what i get from it:

[image: Current State]

So i'd like to ask for help on how to get the same result as the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close !

You're absolutely on the right track using `pushMatrix()`/`popMatrix()` to isolate coordinate systems, however you might have accidentally placed the rotation after `popMatrix()` which defeats the purpose. You probably meant to for each square to have an independent rotation from each other and not accumulate 2 * PI to the global rotation.

The other catch is that you're rotating by the same angle (2 * PI) for each iteration in your for loop and that rotation is 360 degrees so even if you fix rotation like this:

```
pushMatrix();
translate(y, y);
rotate(radians(2.0*PI));
rect(0, 0, a, a);
popMatrix();
```

you'll get a scaling effect:
[image: concentric black squares on white background]
(Minor note 2.0 * PI already exists in Processing as the `TWO_PI` constant)

To get that spiral looking effect is to increment the angle for each iteration (e.g. x = 0, rotation = 0, x = 1, rotation = 5, x = 2, rotation = 10, etc.). The angle increment is totally up to you: depending on how you map the `x` increment to a rotation angle angle you'll get a tighter or looser spiral.

Speaking of mapping, Processing has a [`map()`](https://processing.org/reference/map_.html) function which makes it super easy to map from one range of numbers (let's say x from 0 to 19) to another (let's say 0 radians to PI radians):

```
for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(y, y);
    rotate(map(x, 0, 19, 0, PI));
    rect(0, 0, a, a);
    popMatrix();
    a = a - 20;
  }
```

[image: concentric black squares on white background rotated from centre incrementally]

Here's a basic sketch based on your code:

```
int a = 10;
int y = 250;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  noFill();
  background(255);
  recta();
}

void recta() {
  for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    pushMatrix();
    translate(y, y);
    rotate(map(x, 0, 19, 0, PI));
    rect(0, 0, a, a);
    popMatrix();
    a = a - 20;
  }
}
```

I've removed `draw()` because it was rendering the same frame without any change: drawing once in `setup()` achieves the same visual effect using less CPU/power.

You can use `draw()`, but might as add some interactivity or animation to explore shapes. Here's a tweaked version of the above with comments:

```
int y = 250;

void setup() {
  size(500, 500);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  noFill();
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  recta();
}

void recta() {
  // map mouse X position to -180 to 180 degrees (as radians)
  float maxAngle = map(mouseX, 0, width, -PI, PI);
  // reset square size
  int a = 10;
  // for each square
  for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) {
    // isolate coordinate space
    pushMatrix();
    // translate first
    translate(y, y);
    // then rotate: order matters
    // map x value to mouse mapped maximum rotation angle
    rotate(map(x, 0, 19, 0, maxAngle));
    // render the square
    rect(0, 0, a, a);
    popMatrix();
    // decrease square size
    a = a - 20;
  }
}
```

Remember transformation order matters (e.g. `translate()` then `rotate()` would produce different effects compared to `rotate()` then `translate()`). Have fun!

[image: concentric circles iteratively rotated interactively mapping mouse x position to the maximum angle increment.]

Comment: Thanks a lot dude and you even took the time to tell me things to keep in mind for future projects.